# Is Worksheet Function Weeknum able to take a range?

Tags: vba, excel

When I used a single cell value like Cell(5,34), it works but it didnt work when I have a range of cells.

```
MyRange = Worksheets("POR_Days").Range(Cells(5, 31), Cells(5, 34)).Value

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(3, 31), Cells(3, 34)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(MyRange, 21)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat messy. The default property of range is value, in many cases when you seem to refer to range you actually refer to value in this range. For WeekNum this value is an argument, not a range itself. I would sugges loop through this range and calculate number of week for each single cell:

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim cl As Range

    Set MyRange = Worksheets("POR_Days").Range(Cells(5, 31), Cells(5, 34))

    For Each cl In MyRange
        cl.Offset(-2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(cl, 21)
    Next cl

End Sub
```